# how long time to get approve for Apple Developer Program enrollment?

Tags: ios

I have registered my program with individual type from India and it's already 6 days delay but still now i haven't got any email yet. So how long it will take for the activation.

Comment: What did you use for phone number? It expects a US phone number. Right? @Anshuman Pattnaik

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It usually takes 5 to 7 days for Apple Developer Program enrolment to take place. This may take longer if they have a query, but they will contact you if so.

Comment: Thanks grgarside for your reply so that i have to wait for minimum 7 days and then my account will be activated.

Comment: @AnshumanPattnaik how long did it eventually take?

Comment: Is it normal to stick more than two months and that for individual type?
I tried to contact them multiple times and they said we will contact you once enrolment get updated.